# Entropy of a particle with two energy states

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics

A particle has two energy states having energies $E_0$ and $E_1$ with degeneracies $g_0$ and $g_1$.       The respective probabilities are $p_1$       and $p_2$. What is the entropy in terms of $p_1$, $p_2$, $g_1$ and $g_2$       ?

Comment: See [statistical entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(statistical_thermodynamics)#Gibbs_Entropy_Formula)

Answer (score 4):

In most problems like this, the data $g_1$, $g_2$, $E_0$ and $E_1$ would let you calculate the state occupancy probabilities $p_1$ and $p_2$, through the [Boltzmann Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_distribution). To do this calculation, you would also need the thermodynamic temperature (see the first equations on the Wiki page).

But here $p_1$ and $p_2$ are given to you, as though someone has already done this calculation for you.

So, ask yourself do you really need to know the $E_0$ and $E_1$?

Comment: The OP does need to know the degeneracies, as there are $g_1$ states with probability $p_1$ and $g_2$ states with probability $p_2$, so the entropy has $g_1 + g_2$ terms.